# gnome-terminal command works from command line but not from Cinnamon shortcut (or script)

Tags: linux, bash, gnome-terminal

I am using Linux Mint 17 and Google Chrome.

I often check the weather before going out walking; to do this I surf to http://www.mwis.org.uk/scottish-forecast/EH/ where I then have to click on the PDF doc to see the isobar weather map.

I thought to shorten this process so that the current PDF can be displayed with a simple keyboard shortcut; I've assigned windows key + F8 to this task. However it's not working using gnome-terminal.

I have something wrong with my gnome-terminal syntax, and after some level of googling I'm not really sure what it is.

So, the following does not work, as a shortcut, or when called from a script.

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c myvar=$(curl http://www.mwis.org.uk/scottish-forecast/EH | grep EH-MWI | grep -o -P '(?<=forecasts/).*(?=" target)'); google-chrome http://www.mwis.org.uk/pdf/weather-forecasts/$myvar
```

.. but it does work when placed directly in the command line.

(I started on the command line with

```
myvar=$(curl http://www.mwis.org.uk/scottish-forecast/EH | grep EH-MWI | grep -o -P '(?<=forecasts/).*(?=" target)')
google-chrome http://www.mwis.org.uk/pdf/weather-forecasts/$myvar
```

which does exactly what it is supposed to.)

Can anyone suggest the correct shortcut gnome-terminal command for Cinnamon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `bash -c` needs to be a  single quoted string ("single" as in "one unit", not necessarily specifically within single quotes).

```
bash -c 'google-chrome http://www.mwis.org.uk/pdf/weather-forecasts/"$(curl http://www.mwis.org.uk/scottish-forecast/EH | grep EH-MWI | grep -o -P "(?<=forecasts/).*(?=\" target)")"'
```

I had to change some single quotes to double, as the whole quoted argument obviously cannot contain single quotes (though you could pass it double-quoted instead, or individually backslash-escape each shell metacharacter).

I also factored out the variable.

Comment: hi @tripleee I extended the idea with printing the pdf from another shortcut. I hope U like it. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Looks like your edit was rejected. If you want to include it here for future visitors, feel free to post it as an answer of your own.